# Select the most dissimilar individual using cluster analysis

Tags: r, classification

I want to cluster my data to say 5 clusters, then we need to select 50 individuals with most dissimilar relationship from all the data. That means if cluster one contains 100, two contains 200, three contains 400, four contains 200, and five 100, I have to select 5 from the first cluster + 10 from the second cluster + 20 from the third + 10 from the fourth + 5 from the fifth.

Data example:

```
 mydata<-matrix(nrow=100,ncol=10,rnorm(1000, mean = 0, sd = 1))
```

What I did till now is clustering the data and rank the individuals within each cluster, then export it to excel and go from there … That has become became a problem since my data has became really big.

I will appreciate any help or suggestion on how to apply the previous in R .